# How can I allocate a DataSet larger than will fit in memory in R?

Tags: r, hdf5, rhdf5

I have an external application (non-R) whose input is an HDF5 file containing a dense data cube. I wish to generate the data for that in R.

The normal way to create an HDF5 DataSet in R would be like:

`

```
library(h5)
data <- numeric( 8*8*1000000)
dim(data) <- c(8,8,1000000)
file <- h5file("test.h5", 'w')
file['data'] <- data`
```

This works if there is enough memory to create `data`, but not when the data is large. I can create the data in slices, and could therefore write it into the file, if I could create the DataSet first.

To try to create the dataset, I do

```
file <- h5file("test.h5", 'w')
createDataSet(file, 'data', NA, 'double', c(8,8,1000000))
```

However, R rejects this saying

> unable to find an inherited method for function ‘createDataSet’ for
>   signature ‘"H5File", "character", "numeric", "character", "numeric",
>   "missing", "missing", "missing"'

The calling signature in the [documentation](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/h5/h5.pdf) suggests that "dimensions" is not a vector, but rather an integer--perhaps specifying the number of dimensions. I have experimented with other calling signatures and get mismatch--perhaps the H5File is not a CommonFG type, though CommonFG is a parent class of H5File.